# Oracle Blob binaries different for the same image

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When i trying to store the same image on an oracle table ,
i noticed that the images looks the same **but** the binaries blob file differ.
so i want to know what is the reason about that.
is it something related to the time?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons including (but not limited to):

- different file format (PNG, jpeg, BMP, TIFF, GIF, etc.)
- different settings (high vs low compression, alpha channels, etc.)
- additional meta-data (time, location, comments, camera settings, etc.)